# Ruby library/gem for game graphics?

Tags: ruby, graphics, rubygems

I am creating a simple Blackjack game in Ruby, and I have finished all the game logic stuff (finally!) and currently have it running through the command line. It is all working, so now I need a library or gem that will make the whole graphics side of things easier.
Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe you could try to use *Gosu* which is *a 2D game development library for the Ruby and C++ programming languages, available for Mac OS X, Windows and Linux.*

Available as a gem. More information [here](http://www.libgosu.org/)

You can also watch a fun presentation I saw in Barcelona during Euruko (ruby conference).
Available [Here](http://blip.tv/euruko/euruko2009-fun-with-ruby-and-without-r-s-program-your-own-games-with-gosu-by-javier-ramirez-2442656)

Comment: The video link is broken.

Answer (score 11):

As well as Gosu, mentioned elsewhere, there's [Rubygame](http://rubygame.org/) which also appears to be regularly updated.

No opinion on either, suggested as an alternative for comparison.

UPDATE: New(-ish?) kid on the block: [Ray](http://mon-ouie.github.com/projects/ray.html). Fairly graphically-oriented, it would appear.

Comment: I have been using Rubygame for a while. It looks it is enough for a hobby project in 2D. I haven't try to do something bigger.

Comment: I've just checked out both Gosu and Rubygame; both are awesome but Rubygame looks to be on the backburner - it is not being updated. Gosu has a lot more recent activity and active forums. The [Ruby tutorial for Gosu](https://github.com/jlnr/gosu/wiki/Ruby-Tutorial) is great for a beginner.

Answer (score 5):

[Shoes](http://wiki.github.com/shoes/shoes) would be a good candidate, it's very lightweight, cross platform & fun to use.

It has a nice ruby API which you can use to draw shapes and use native GUI widgets.